# Struggling to get Laravel 5.2 Database Session working - Something wrong with my config?

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, persistence

I have an existing Laravel 5.2 application that I need to add features to.

I have the following requirement

1. To have a controller that will serve multiple requests, each
   request sending a unique ID to identify it's source
2. **There will be no authentication**
3. To be able to save session information to the database

What I have done:

1. in `config/session.php`, I set the session driver as follows: `'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),`
2. The database is setup and user details configured (mysql)
3. From the CLI, I ran `php artisan session:table`, then `php artisan migrate`
4. From my controller, in the first call, create a test session variable using my (emulated) unique ID(555): `\Session::put(555, ['a' => 'Value1']);`
5. Under that line, I read and Log the session variable: `\Log::info(print_r(\Session::get(555))` - **It works! Outputs as expected!**
6. Then a second call comes in, I expect to be able to read that session variable, that was persisted by using: `\Log::info( is_array(\Session::get(555)) ? print_r(\Session::get(555),1) : 'No value')` - checks if it's an array and prints it out - **Does not work. No value!**

I have gone through the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session) and various posts on the subject, I can't seem to get it to persist.

Even tried using `\Session::save();` immediately after setting the session.

Answer (score 0):

Your session gets lost in the 'lottery' sweep. Change this line in /config/session.php

```
'lottery' => [2, 100],
```

to

```
'lottery' => [0, 100],
```

And it should work.

Comment: As a side note: working with sessions on what you want to achieve is tricky. You may have to consider using cookies instead. You can serialize any amount of data to one cookie.